# I want .tabcontent to appear from 0 center to full size animated over .3 seconds

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

[Sample of hover effect](http://jsfiddle.net/RussB804/DLBPF/99/#&togetherjs=Vzfx8e7TQi)

I want the hover effect to be animated starting from 0 center out to full size over  0.3s. The effect is what I want ,but the animation isn't working.The page I'm going to build will consist of eight different images (two columns four in each) I want this hover effect to work as you  hove hover each image.

```css
#tabbox{
 height: 300px;
 position: relative;
 //border: 2px solid #888;
}

#tabbox img{
 cursor: pointer;
 display: block;
 width: 240px;
 height: 240px;
}

.tab {
 float: left;
}

.tabcontent{
 position: absolute;
 padding:10px;
 top:0;
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
 background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
 border:1px solid #fff;
 margin:10px;
 color:#fff;
 display:none;
 overflow:hidden;
 -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.tabcontent:before{
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 -webkit-transform: scale(0);
 transform: scale(0);
 -webkit-transition-property: transform;
 transition-property: transform;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
 transition-duration: 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
 transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.tab:hover > .tabcontent{
 display: block;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
}

.tab:hover:before, .tab:active:before{
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div id="tabbox">
 <div class="tab">
  <img src="http://zone1.gingermartinco.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Napa-Real-Estate-Realtor.jpg" />
  <div class="tabcontent">
   <p>Text box to describe the images around when you hover over them, this description will change depending on what image you hover over.</p>
  </div><!--tabcontent-->
 </div><!--tab-->
</div><!--tabbox-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the  `display: none;` from `.tabcontent` as this property can't be animated, only number properties can be animated.

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/uxouomoy/

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle and your question code is not the same.
But taking the code from the fiddle you should put the transition only in `.tabcontent` style. Use top and left properties to animate from the center position to the left corner position.

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9bqytcd/2/)

Here's the css it is using:

```css
#tabbox {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  //border: 2px solid #888;

}
#tabbox img {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
}
.tab {
  float: left;
}
.tabcontent {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition: width top left;
}
.tab:hover > .tabcontent {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabbox">
  <div class="tab">
    <img src="http://zone1.gingermartinco.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Napa-Real-Estate-Realtor.jpg" />
    <div class="tabcontent">
      <p>Text box to describe the images around when you hover over them, this description will change depending on what image you hover over.</p>

    </div>
    <!--tabcontent-->
  </div>
  <!--tab-->


</div>
<!--tabbox-->
```